# Spring Boot OAuth 2 configuration with DB instead of inmemory

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

Below code uses inmemory to save the tokens in session, is it possible to store the tokens in DB and retrieve it from the same ?

whether the below code will give performance issue?

```
@Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients 
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
                        /*.accessTokenValiditySeconds(2400)
                        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(4800);*/
            // @formatter:on
        }
```

Comment: This repository has MongoDB implementation: https://github.com/caelwinner/spring-security-mongo

Comment: But I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

**In memory will be faster** than accessing data from database. **But,** if multiple clients are consuming this then it is better to have it in database instead of hard coding all the details in the Java file.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) for the tables required to store the client and other details. 
And you have to use **.jdbc()** method instead of **.inMemory()** in the client object to access the details from the database.

Comment: but when I use In memory, tokens will be cleared if I restart the server. again user have to enter the credentials to login.

Comment: You need to create **JdbcTokenStore** with datasource reference and configure **AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer** endpoint to use this token store. Also you have to crate "oauth_refresh_token" and "oauth_access_token" as given in the link above

Comment: now I can access tokens from DB but I am getting the below exception once the token expires. **org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientAlreadyExistsException** when I refer the [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/420), they asked to remove **withClient()**. But I am not able to remove it from the project :(

Comment: Why you are not able to remove from the project?

Comment: when I remove **withClient()** method from the above code, it's throwing undefined exception on **authorizedGrantTypes()** method @ravindra Devadiga

Comment: Have you created **oauth_client_details** table as it is mentioned in the link??

Comment: yeah created all the 7 tables in DB @Ravindra Devdiga